# Gets 401 error while user tries to do Fetch Get request after authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to get user details after user looged in but user is getting 401 error even user is looged in with 200 ok.

- Explanation of process:
- i have logged in user using fetch post request.
- stored username,role,staffid to async storage
- now i want to list all user (with `/api/staff`  endpoint response throws user firstname and last name )with fetch get request but whenever i make `GET` request it
  throws `401` error.
  It will be lifesaver to crack this step for me,thank you!

here is my code

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, Alert } from "react-native";
import AuthService from "../api/auth-service";
import BASE_URL from "../api/baseUrl";

export default function HomeScreen(props) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState({});
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState({});

  const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (mounted) {
      getDataFromStorage();
      getUserInfo();
    }
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  const getDataFromStorage = async () => {
    let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("LoggedInUser");
    setUserValue(JSON.parse(user));
  };

       const getUserInfo=async()=>{
  return fetch(BASE_URL+"/api/staff")
  .then((response) => { 
    if(response.ok){
    console.log(response);
    }else{
      console.log(response.status);
      
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({ errorMsg: "Error retreiving data" });
  });
}

 return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>
        {"Good morning " + userValue.username + "  "}
        {"you role is  " + userValue.role +"your staff id is " + userValue.staffId+" " + "your first name is "+ firstName +"this is your last name"+lastName} 
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

authservice.js

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import BASE_URL from "./baseUrl";

class AuthService {
  login(Username, Password, role) {
    console.log(Username, role);

    return fetch(BASE_URL + "/api/authentication/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Username,
        Password,
      }),
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        console.log("the login response", res);
        return res.json();
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Username or Password");
        window.stop();
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((keys) => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys));
      }
}
export default new AuthService();
```

login.js

```
const submitData = async () => {
 AuthService.login(Username, Password).then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        AsyncStorage.setItem("LoggedInUser", JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.role == "Admin") {
          console.log(data.username);
          navigation.navigate("adminPage");
        } else {
          navigation.navigate("staffpage");
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        Alert.alert(error);
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: `getDataFromStorage` is asynchronous function so you have to resolve it first and after that execute `getUserInfo`

Comment: I did but still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)

> The HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

It's seems the user doesn't have right to access the API. Make sure that the getUserInfo() API, /api/staff, don't need any authentication token in header of your HTTP request.

Comment: user need authentication to get the data. how can i make that header don't need authentication token for HTTP request?

Comment: As much as I know this is not possible unless the server doesn't need it. So it's better you save the token you get from the server after login in localStorage, so you can access it afterward wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you may need to resolve one more promise in `AuthService.login`.

`res.json()` is actually a promise which needs to be resolved as well, so you may need one more `then` block like so:

```js
return fetch(BASE_URL + "/api/authentication/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Username,
        Password,
      }),
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        console.log("the login response", res);
        return res.json();
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Username or Password");
        window.stop();
      }
    }).then(finalData=>finalData )// <---------- add this
      .catch(err=> err)
```

Comment: tried this one but I'm still getting same error `401 unauthorized`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `getDataFromStorage` is an async function so you have to resolve it first. Also in login.js we have to await before navigate to make sure that the data is saved in AsyncStorage. Please update the following part of your code:

login.js

```
const submitData = async () => {
 AuthService.login(Username, Password).then(
      async (data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("LoggedInUser", JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.role == "Admin") {
          console.log(data.username);
          navigation.navigate("adminPage");
        } else {
          navigation.navigate("staffpage");
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        Alert.alert(error);
      }
    );
  };
```

next, initialize `userValue` with null

```
const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState(null);
```

Now have 2 useEffect,

```
useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true; //Why this required as it doesn't mean anything
  if (!userValue) {
    getDataFromStorage();
  }
  return () => {
    mounted = false;
  };   
}, []);
```

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(userValue){
    getUserInfo()
  }
},[userValue])
```

Comment: I got it, since state set is also asynchronous we have to add another useEffect. Updated my answer

Comment: `net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)` still same problem

Comment: yes i did , it throws `401 error ` twice after updated code. `401 (Unauthorized)` and `net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Ok, may be console.log of getDataFromStorage returning correct user. Updated code with removing of twice 401

Comment: Throws `401 error` but only one time. I have tried using postman and swagger both for server side it is working but for client side I'm still getting error.

Comment: It is not working. i think i was able to login successfully but after login when i try to fetch get request it was not able to know if user is login.Is this issue is related to session storage or cookies related ? because to fetch get request the user role should be `staff` and based on role user is authorize to hit that endpoint `api/staff`